# Using Joins to query two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, "inventory" and "inventory_type". The "inventory" table stores the name of it and the type, and the "inventory_type" table stores the type name such as RAM, CPU, etc. and the sort order. I have never used JOINS before and I am not sure which type to use, but none of them seem to work with the following code.

As a side question, with my code below, would "inventory" be the left table or would "inventory_type" be joined in on the left?

```
function getInventoryOptions($db, $default_value, $datacenter)
{
    $query = "SELECT inventory.id, inventory.name, inventory_type.short_name
                FROM inventory LEFT JOIN inventory_type
                ON inventory.type = inventory_type.id WHERE inventory.datacenter = " . $datacenter . " ORDER BY inventory_type.sort_order ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

    echo '<option value="">None</option>';

    if ($result)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $row["inventory.id"];
            $name = $row["inventory.name"];
            $type = $row["inventory_type.short_name"];

            if ($default_value == $id)
            {
                echo '<option selected value="' . $id . '">' . $type . ": " . $name . '</option>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $type . ": " . $name . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'none of them seem to work'? The query looks fine, you need to post a sample of datas.

Comment: use print_r($result) just after $result = mysqli_query($query,$db) to debug the dataset

Comment: Is $id = $row["inventory.id"]; the correct way to get the value? I did a var_dump() and it does seem to be returning data, just seems I am not fetching it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

```
$id = $row["inventory.id"];
$name = $row["inventory.name"];
$type = $row["inventory_type.short_name"];
```

try:

```
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$type = $row['short_name'];
```

---

* Note that the mysql extension [is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

**UPDATE**

Here's the equivalent of your function in mysqli:

```
function getInventoryOptions($db, $default_value, $datacenter)
{
     $query = "SELECT inventory.id, inventory.name, inventory_type.short_name
               FROM inventory LEFT JOIN inventory_type
               ON inventory.type = inventory_type.id WHERE inventory.datacenter = " . $datacenter . " ORDER BY inventory_type.sort_order ASC";

$link = mysqli_connect("[your_host]","[your_user]","[password]","[database]") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));



//execute the query.

$result = $link->query($query);

//display information:

while($row = mysqli_fecth_array($result)) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $type = $row['short_name'];

        if ($default_value == $id)
        {
            echo '<option selected value="' . $id . '">' . $type . ": " . $name . '</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $type . ": " . $name . '</option>';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that the `inventory.type` column is `not null` (please confirm that) there's no need for a `LEFT JOIN`. A `INNER JOIN` will do the trick.

Since you only need an associative array, consider using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`, or specify `MYSQL_ASSOC` as a second parameter.

Moreover, consider porting to `mysqli` or `PDO` altogether (see others' replies).

The returned associative array's keys are plain field names, without the table name part.

Finally, for your side question, yes, `inventory` would be the left table, with all its records participating in the result regardless of whether or not there's a corresponding record in the `inventory_type` table.